# Wrap Latex Equation using custom tag PHP regex

Tags: php, regex, latex

I just want to wrap the Math latex equation using any html tag. The string be like

`y = x2  or \(x = \sqrt{y}\) . For all \(y \geq 0\), x is defined. Thus, y is set of all non-negative and real number. Hence, range is \(y \geq 0\) or [0, ∞).`

I want output like

`y = x2  or <math>\(x = \sqrt{y}\)</math> . For all <math>\(y \geq 0\)</math>, x is defined. Thus, y is set of all non-negative and real number. Hence, range is <math>\(y \geq 0\)</math> or [0, ∞).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern for equation seems like this:

```regex
((\\\()((?!(\\\()|(\\\))).)*(\\\)))
```

The prefix `(\\\()` and suffix `(\\\))` are simple check for start and end of the equation.

The middle part `((?!(\\\()|(\\\))).)*` count any character (`.`) (except \n) unless by looking ahead "`(?! ...)`" the two character in front be one of `\(` or `\)`.

The whole equation pattern are in `(...)`, so it could be referred to as group1 or `$1`. So that should be substituted by:

```
<math>$1</math>
```

[Link to test for PHP PCRE2](https://regex101.com/r/7OSy7L/1)